# How to send post request using raw json with volley or retrofit in android

Tags: android, post, http-post, retrofit, android-volley

I am not able to send raw post request and receive a response from the server

[image]

Comment: This question looks like it may contain sensitive information. Consider editing or deleting your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void login() {

       RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
       String URL = "https://api-test01.moneyboxapp.com/users/login";

       final String requestBody = "{\"Email\":\"androidtest@moneyboxapp.com\",\"Password\":\"P455word12\",\"Idfa\":\"ANYTHING\"}";

       StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(String response) {
               Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
           }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
           }
       }) {
           @Override
           public String getBodyContentType() {
               return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
           }

           @Override
           public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
               try {
                   return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
               } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                   VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                   return null;
               }
           }

           @Override
           public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
               Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
               params.put("AppId", "3a97b932a9d449c981b595");
               params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
               params.put("appVersion","5.10.0");
               params.put("apiVersion","3.0.0");

               return params;
           }
           @Override
           protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
               String responseString = "";
               if (response != null) {
                   responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                   // can get more details such as response.headers
               }
               return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
           }
       };

       requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```